# As we all know constructor is not having a returning type but in the code below constructor is returning...can any one explain

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

This is the code:
As you see in the code, constructor is a used as a returning type but i have read that       it returns nothing even not void. kindly explain.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class complex_1
{
    float x,y;
public:
    complex_1() {}
    complex_1(float a) {x=y=a;}
    complex_1(float real, float imag )
    {x=real;y=imag;}
    complex_1 operator+(complex_1);
    void display(void);
};
complex_1 complex_1::operator+(complex_1 c)
{
    c.x= x + c.x;
    c.y= y + c.y;
    return c;
}
void complex_1::display(void)
{
    cout<<x<<" + "<<y<<"j"<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    complex_1 A(2.7, 3.5);
    complex_1 B(1.2);
    complex_1 C;
    //C=A.operator+(B);   // equivalent to C = A + B;
    C=A+B;
    cout<<"A =  ";
    A.display();
    cout<<"B =  "; 
    B.display();
    cout<<"C =  ";
    C.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any constructor returning anything, care to elaborate?

Comment: "As you see in the code" - no I cannot see it. Can you be more explicit about what is confusing you?

Comment: "constructor is a used as a returning type" no it isn't.

Comment: complex_1 complex_1::operator+(complex_1 c)  In the definition it's 'c' returning which is a object.

Comment: In the definition part of "complex_1 complex_1::operator+(complex_1 c)" return is used.I want to know why it is used as "return c".

Comment: In a function such as `int some_func(int c) { /* do some stuff */ return c; }`, is the return weird there? No? It's just the same here.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
complex_1 complex_1::operator+(complex_1 c)
```

is a definition of a class `complex_1` member function (`complex_1::` means this) that returns an object of type `complex_1`.

`c` is not a constructor but an object of type `complex_1` that is returned in this function.

Comment: In the definition part "return c" is used.I want to know why it is used as "return c".

Comment: Because `c` is the object that the `operator+` member function wants to return?

Answer (score 0):

Constructor constructs in-place, it has no need to return anything.

Constructors aren't called like normal functions

Following aren't return anything

```
complex_1 A(2.7, 3.5);
complex_1 B(1.2);
complex_1 C;
```

Comment: In the definition part of "complex_1 complex_1::operator+(complex_1 c)" return is used.I want to know why it is used as "return c".

Comment: @kumar `return c` is used to return the updated `c` object which is of type `complex_1` as a result of addition performed on the data members

Comment: @Kumar: Note that `operator+` is not a constructor, it is an overloaded binary `+`(addition) operator. Read about operator overloading.

Answer (score 0):

It's the operator+ returning which you wrote it in conjoint manner. Omit it out the constructor you find that constructor has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The `operator+` function isn't using the constructor at all. It's modifying the parameter `c` that was passed in (which is a copy of the original), then returning it. The compiler will use the copy constructor before it makes the function call.